# How to retrieve latest played song?

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, android-mediaplayer, android-music-player

I'm creating a music player playlist which has recently played songs in it. I'm storing the songs' arraylist and the index of the song which is being played in shared preferences. What I'm doing to get the recently played songs is retrieving the arraylist and the song index from shared preferences and save it in another arraylist. But the problem is the recyclerView displays only one song at a time.

Example, if I played song A, the recyclerView should show me song A at first position, then if I play song B, recyclerView should show song B in first position and song A in second position. But it only shows the first position.

`RecentlyPLayedsongs.java`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View view6 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_recently_played, null);
    FrameLayout container6 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
    container6.addView(view6);

    recyclerView_recently_played = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_recently_played);

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView_recently_played.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    StorageUtil storageUtil2 = new StorageUtil(getApplicationContext());

    SongList=storageUtil2.loadAudio();

    pos = storageUtil2.loadAudioIndex();

    songInfoModel = SongList.get(pos);

    RecentlyPlayedList.add(songInfoModel);

    adapter1 = new Playlist_Recently_Added_Adapter(RecentlyPlayedList, getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView_recently_played.setAdapter(adapter1);

}
```

Comment: that means you are adding on 2nd position of the array when song b is played?

Comment: I want song A to be added to second position when song B is being played and song B to the first position just like in normal music players

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via below one of two ways

1. Before passing the song list you need to sort according to time. In this case, you also need to save time when you play a song.(Well, to achieve this you need to do a lot of coding and it's maintainance)
2. This is far more easy way. You can use **add()** method of Array list and you can specify position there as well as mentioned in below code

   list.add(o, currentSong);

Here 0 is being passed that means whenever you are playing a song that will be added at 0 index that means your latest played song will always be on the top.
Hope that helps you.

NOTE: I have verified second solution with below code that works as expected

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(3);

    Log.d(TAG, "firs time");
    for (int a=0; a < list.size();a++ ) {
        Log.d(TAG, "" + list.get(a));
    }

    list.add(0,4);

    Log.d(TAG, "second time");
    for (int a=0; a < list.size();a++ ) {
        Log.d(TAG, "" + list.get(a));
    }
```

The logs were as mentioned below

```
11-19 11:24:53.400 3681-3681/com.example.awaheed.datetime D/test: firs time
11-19 11:24:53.400 3681-3681/com.example.awaheed.datetime D/test: 1
11-19 11:24:53.400 3681-3681/com.example.awaheed.datetime D/test: 2
11-19 11:24:53.400 3681-3681/com.example.awaheed.datetime D/test: 3
11-19 11:24:53.400 3681-3681/com.example.awaheed.datetime D/test: second time
11-19 11:24:53.400 3681-3681/com.example.awaheed.datetime D/test: 4
11-19 11:24:53.400 3681-3681/com.example.awaheed.datetime D/test: 1
11-19 11:24:53.400 3681-3681/com.example.awaheed.datetime D/test: 2
11-19 11:24:53.400 3681-3681/com.example.awaheed.datetime D/test: 3
```

Have a look at the log of second time number was added at '0' index and not that is on first position and remaing items are pushed down. Hope that makes some sense.

Comment: Like I said, I'm using the add() method of arraylist, but it only adds the latest song to the first place, the previous songs are not shown below in the recyclerView. Hope you are getting my point.

Comment: Like I mentioned, I am using add method but specifying position as well if you try to do so you will be adding your song at first position and remaining songs will automatically be pushed below first song. Give it a try. then let me know

Comment: I tried that before. Didn't succeed. Only song is added whatsoever.

Comment: I have tested that is working fine as i mentioned in my answer. I am adding piece of code on that I tested have a look at that

Comment: Yeah I see it, but in your case it is an integer value but in my case it is a custom object. And this code `RecentlyPlayedList.add(songInfoModel);` adds one song at a time

Comment: I can't do `RecentlyPlayedList.add(songInfoModel);` multiple times as it will the same object everytime